# How to remotely pay property tax in Netherlands?

Tags: taxes, netherlands, housing, non-residents

I am Lithuanian citizen that lives in UK, I have bought a flat in Holland, and there is possibility that I will be leaving the country for some time to SE Asia, so I was planning on renting it out.

I have never payed tax before in Netherlands and not sure how the whole thing works. [From here as I understand](http://www.expatax.nl/box-3.php) I would be paying 1.2% of property value per year.

I do have Dutch bank account open and BSN. I am currently still in UK so still could come to Holland in person to set things up. But after January chances are I would have to fly from SE Asia if I would need to deal with matters in person, so would rather prepare everything now.

**Is there a way to set up all the tax accounts and pay the tax remotelly?**

Comment: Depends on how long you work in the UK, you might be client for UK tax office and not for NL one

Comment: I'm quite sure this can all be handled online at the belastingdienst.nl site (fill in an income tax return for the relevant year(s) online), but it's too much work for me to find all the relevant English-language pages.